# What is the origin of Bishy Barney Bee?

Tags: etymology, british-english, entomology

The attached picture is of a delightful little creature which throughout the UK is known as a Ladybird (not sure what you call them in America) EXCEPT in Norfolk, where it is known as a 'Bishy Barney Bee'. The name is believed to be derived from Bishop Bonner who lived during the 16th century, and was known notoriously as 'Bloody Bonner' for his ruthless persecution of Protestants under Mary I.

I would be very interested to discover more about the connection between Bishop Bonner and the Ladybird. Can anyone help me please?

The British among you will know of the nursery rhyme which is recited with a Ladybird in your hand and at the end releasing it to fly away.

In Norfolk it goes:
Bishy Bishy Barney Bee,
Fly away home,
Your house is on fire,
And your children all gone.

Perhaps the rhyme has some connection to Bishop Bonner, though throughout the rest of the UK it is recited as :
Ladybird, ladybird, fly away home etc.

[image: Bishy Barney Bee]

Comment: I can't actually believe that someone has given this a negative vote. Why?

Comment: The OED seems to known nothing about the Bishy Barney Bee.

Comment: FYI, Americans (at least in my experience) call them "ladybugs," and the rhyme is otherwise identical.

Comment: @apsillers  'Bug' sounds quite a pejorative name for a harmless, and rather beautiful little bee that runs contentedly up your arm.

Comment: The red or yellow-orange species *[Harmonia axyridis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonia_axyridis)* has names like *harlequin ladybird, multicolored Asian lady beetle, Halloween lady beetle*

Comment: Bugs can also be spoken of endearingly in expressions such as "as snug as a bug in a rug". :-)

Comment: Perhaps relating to having a bee in one's bonnet, this is the Bishop's bloody bee.

Comment: Technically, this is not a bee, nor a bug (nor a bird), but a beetle.  However zoological technicalities do not determine common speech.

Comment: Norfolk has Dutch and Belgium (Flemish) influences. The ladybird is called; lieveheersbeestje…….. lieve(sweet) heer(lord) beestje(small animal)

Comment: Interesting. Norfolk took huge numbers of Flemish and Walloon refugees - fleeing the Spanish Inquisition - from the 14th century on. During the late-eighteenth century one third of the population of Norwich was made up of "Strangers" as they were called. But I have never seen anything on the influence of Flemish on the Norfolk dialect. And I have read Professor Peter Trudgill - undoubtedly the leading academic authority on the dialect. I feel sure if there were links he would have drawn attention to them.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. The Dutch word for a ladybird doesn’t seem relevant at all here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From an article in the [Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/education/3353415/Tooterin-folk-in-Norfolk-talkin.html)

> A "bishy-barney-bee", the most striking example, is the local word
>   for a ladybird (it is said that it was inspired by a Bishop Barnabas
>   of Norwich, who wore a similarly coloured cloak).

I suspected the journalist committed a mistake and meant to say a Bishop of St Barnabus
because I could find no trace of there ever being a Bishop Barnabus in Norfolk. [<sup>1</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bishop_of_Norwich#List_of_bishops_of_Norwich)

There is however a St Barnabus church in Norwich but as it was first built in 1903 the dates do not match. Perhaps The telegraph journalist was onto something when claiming that the Bishop wore a red cloak.

Traditionally Catholic Bishops wear a long cloak called a [cappa magna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cope#Cappa_magna).
[Images](https://www.google.com/search?q=Cappa+magna&client=firefox-a&hs=PAp&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=rcs&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=Ad5wUo7PEYi27QaP1YCwBA&ved=0CC0QsAQ&biw=1366&bih=586#channel=rcs&q=%22Cappa+magna%22&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial&tbm=isch)

> The cappa magna (literally, "great cape"), a form of mantle, is a
>   voluminous ecclesiastical vestment with a long train, proper to
>   cardinals, bishops, and certain other honorary prelates. It is however
>   a jurisdictional garment.
>
> The cappa magna is not strictly a liturgical vestment, but only a
>   glorified cappa choralis, or choir cope. That is to say, it is not
>   used when vested as a celebrant at a liturgical service. It is worn in
>   processions or "in choir" (i.e., attending but not celebrating
>   services). **Its colour for cardinals is ordinarily red and for bishops
>   violet.**

From Google books I found this excerpt from a book entitled *Frommer's England With Your Family* which has a different nursery rhyme.

[image]

A [**second version**](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/13521/13521-h/13521-h.htm#page131) of the children's nursery rhyme names the ladybird as "*Bishop Barnabee*"

> "Bishop, Bishop Barnabee,
>
> Tell me when my wedding be;
>
> If it be to-morrow day,
>
> Take your wings and fly away!
>
> Fly to the east, fly to the west,
>
> Fly to them that I love best!"

And finally this [book](http://books.google.it/books?id=Pb-86Ls1zwoC&pg=PA70&dq=Bishy&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lcxwUuiCI4Oq7QaN8oCwAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Bishy&f=false) yielded this snippet of information. I've also included the nursery rhyme in standard English.

[image]

Comment: Very well done!

Answer (score 1):

There are some useful notes at para 132 of this:
[NOTES AND QUERIES: A MEDIUM OF INTER-COMMUNICATION FOR LITERARY MEN, ARTISTS, ANTIQUARIES, GENEALOGISTS, ETC.](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/13521/13521-h/13521-h.htm)

No. 9.  SATURDAY, DECEMBER 29, 1849 Price Threepence.
Stamped Edition 4d.

> ### BISHOP BARNABY.
>
> Mr. Editor,—Allow me, in addition to the Note inserted in your 4th Number, in answer to the Query of LEGOUR, by your correspondent (and I believe my friend) J.G., to give the following extract from Forby's *Vocabulary of East Anglia*:—
>
> > "Bishop Barnabee-s. The pretty insect more generally called the
> >     Lady-bird, or May-bug. It is one of those highly favoured among God's
> >     harmless creatures which superstition protects from wanton injury.
> >     Some obscurity seems to hang over this popular name of it. It
> >     has certainly no more relation to the companion of St. Paul than to
> >     drunken Barnaby, though some have supposed it has. It is sometimes
> >     called *Bishop Benebee,* which may possibly have been intended to mean
> >     the *blessed bee*; sometimes *Bishop Benetree,* of which it seems not
> >     possible to make any thing. The name has most probably been derived
> >     from the *Barn-Bishop*; whether in scorn of that silly and profane
> >     mockery, or in pious commemoration of it, must depend on the time of
> >     its adoption, before or since the Reformation; and it is not worth
> >     inquiring. The two words are transposed, and *bee* annexed as being
> >     perhaps thought more seemly in such a connection than fly-bug or
> >     beetle. The dignified ecclesiastics in ancient times wore brilliant
> >     mixtures of colours in their habits. Bishops had scarlet and black, as
> >     this insect has on its wing-covers. Some remains of the finery of the
> >     gravest personages still exist on our academical robes of ceremony.
> >     There is something inconsistent with the popish episcopal character in
> >     the childish rhyme with which *Bishop Barnabee* is thrown up and
> >     dismissed when he happens to light on any one's hand. Unluckily the
> >     words are not recollected, nor at present recoverable; but the purport
> >     of them is to admonish him to fly home, and take care of his wife and
> >     children, for that his house in on fire. Perhaps, indeed, the rhyme
> >     has been fabricated long since the name by some one who did not think
> >     of such niceties."
>
> G.A.C.
>
> Sir,—In the explanation of the term Bishop Barnaby, given by J.G., the
>   prefix "Bishop" seems yet to need elucidation. Why should it not have
>   arisen from the insect's garb? The full dress gown of the Oxford
>   D.D.—scarlet with black velvet sleeves—might easily have suggested the
>   idea of naming the little insect "Dr. Burn bug," and the transition is
>   easy to "Dr. Burnabee," or "Bishop Burnaby." These little insects, in
>   the winter, congregate by thousands in barns for their long slumber
>   till the reappearance of genial weather, and it is not impossible
>   that, from this circumstance, the country people may have designated
>   them "Barn bug," or "Barn bee."
>
> L.B.L.
>
> Sir,—I cannot inform LEGOUR why the lady-bird (the seven-spotted,
>   *Coccinella Septempunctata,* is the most common) is called in some
>   places "Bishop Barnaby." This little insect is sometimes erroneously
>   accused of destroying turnips and peas in its larva state; but, in
>   truth, both in the larva and perfect state it feeds exclusively on
>   aphides. I do not know that it visits dairies, and Tusser's "Bishop
>   that burneth," may allude to something else; still there appears some
>   popular connection of the *Coccinellidæ* with *cows* as well as burning,
>   for in the West Riding of Yorkshire they are called *Cush Cow Ladies*;
>   and in the North Riding one of the children's rhymes anent them runs:—
>
> > "Dowdy-cow, dowdy-cow, ride away heame, 
> > Thy<sup>1</sup> house is burnt, and thy
> >     bairns are tean, 
> > And if thou means to save thy bairns 
> > Take thy wings
> >     and flee away!"
>
> The most mischievous urchins are afraid to hurt the
>   dowdy-cow, believing if they did evil would inevitably befall them. It
>   is tenderly placed on the palm of the hand—of a girl, if possible—and
>   the above rhyme recited thrice, during which it usually spreads its
>   wings, and at the last word flies away. A collection of nursery rhymes
>   relating to insects would, I think, be useful.
>
> W.G.M.J. BARKER.
>
> ---
>
> Footnote 1: *Thy* is pronounced as *thee.*
>
> [We have received many other communications respecting the epithet of
>   this insect—so great a favourite with children. ALICUI and several
>   other correspondents incline to L.B.L.'s opinion that it takes its
>   name from a fancied resemblance of its bright wing-cases to the
>   episcopal cope or chasuble. J.T. reminds us that St. Barnabas has been
>   distinguished of old by the title of *bright,* as in the old proverbial
>   distich intended to mark the day of his festival according to the Old
>   Style (21st June):—
>
> > "Barnaby bright! 
> > The longest day and the shortest night."
>
> While F.E.
>   furnishes us with another and happier version of the Norfolk popular
>   rhyme:—
>
> > "Bishop, Bishop Barnabee, Tell me when *my* wedding be; 
> > If it be
> >     to-morrow day, 
> > Take your wings and fly away! 
> > *Fly to the east, fly to
> >     the west, 
> > Fly to them that I love best!*"
>
> The name which this pretty
>   insect bears in the various languages of Europe is clearly mythic. In
>   this, as in other cases, the Virgin has supplanted Freya; so that
>   *Freyjuhaena* and *Frouehenge* have been changed into *Marienvoglein,* which
>   corresponds with *Our Lady's Bird.* There, can, therefore, be little
>   doubt that the esteem with which the lady-bird, or Our Lady's cow, is
>   still regarded, is a relic of the ancient cult.]

and the OED article "[East Anglian English](http://public.oed.com/aspects-of-english/english-in-use/east-anglian-english/)", by Peter Trudgill, usefully says:

> *Bishybarnybee* ‘ladybird’ is not an ancient word—instead it comes from ‘Bishop Bonner’s bee’. Bishop Edmund ‘Bloody’ Bonner, who had been vicar in the Norfolk town of East Dereham, became bishop of London in 1539 and was known as a ferocious persecutor of protestant martyrs during the reign of Queen Mary.

Comment: ... and the OED usefully says:

"Bishybarnybee ‘ladybird’ is not an ancient word—instead it comes from ‘Bishop Bonner’s bee’. Bishop Edmund ‘Bloody’ Bonner, who had been vicar in the Norfolk town of East Dereham, became bishop of London in 1539 and was known as a ferocious persecutor of protestant martyrs during the reign of Queen Mary." (see: http://public.oed.com/aspects-of-english/english-in-use/east-anglian-english/)

Comment: Please edit your answer to include the comment: answers should include source, context and explanation. Link-only answers are subject to deletion for LQ.

Comment: @RichardThresh in the etymology of their actual definition though they say 'Attempts to link the word with either a real-life Bishop Barnaby (no such historical figure is known) or with St Barnabas Day (11 June) may be dismissed as fanciful. A connection with Edmund Bonner (d. 1569), bishop of London, known as ‘Bloody Bonner’, a notorious persecutor of Protestant martyrs, has also been suggested (positing an original form *Bishop Bonner bee )' which is much less assertive, and they suggest 'Burnie-bee' as the older form.

Answer (score -1):

Edmund Bonner was responsible for dispensing many death sentences on Protestants during Queen Mary's purges. He did this in what became known as "Bloody Assises", and this got him the name of Bloody Bonner. This suggests a likely derivation for Bishy Barnaby, as Bishop Bonner's Bee, the red colour offering the link.